# Does Telekinetic Projectile allow choosing both projectile and target within range even if they are further apart than 30 feet?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-2e

Telekinetic Projectile allows you to "hurl [an] object that is within range [...] at the target". The spell's range is 30 feet.

My reading of this is that both the target and the object must be picked from within 30 feet from the caster. But nothing states that the path that the projectile flies (from object to target) must be less than 30 feet.

Are my assumptions correct or have I missed any relevant rules?

Also, if so, does the path between them have to be clear as to not provide Cover for the target?

```
Object <- 30ft -> caster <- 30ft -> target
       <-         ~60ft          ->
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Telekinetic Projectile* (Core Rulebook, pg. 377) has  range of 30 ft and targets "1 creature". That explicitly means that the target must be within 30 feet.

The description (as you quoted) starts out:

> You hurl a loose, unattended object that is within range ...

Therefore, the object being hurled must also be within 30 feet. As you said, it's possible for the target and the object to be more than 30 feet apart (up to a maximum of 60 feet).

None of this has any relevance to determining cover.The cover rules (Core Rulebook, pg. 477 +) are explicit about cover being based on a direct line between you and your target:

> If you're uncertain or need to be more precise [about whether cover applies], draw a line from the center of your space to the center of the target's space. If that line passes through any terrain or object that would block the effect, the target has standard cover ...

The location of the object doesn't matter, nor do any terrain or obstacles between the object and the target.

Comment: The cover rules you mentioned only seem to handle how _you_ would calculate cover from another target. Are there perhaps rules handling things like a radial burst from a Fireball spell, since those are from a point you specify?
That said, the cover may just be up to the GM to determine

Comment: @Wigglemaster Things that target an area work differently. The "Areas" and "Line of Effect" rules (pg. 457) don't specifically mention cover, but probably do what you want. Telekinetic Projectile doesn't use those rules, since it targets a creature.